# Confused with AngularJS ng-options

Tags: json, angularjs, ng-options

I have this JSON (output extracted from Mozilla Firefox):

```
2015: Object
   02: Object
    monthname: "February"
   01: Object
    monthname: "January"
```

So, i want to use AngularJS directive: ngOptions.

I don't know how to access to these objects. I want to reproduce something like:

```
<select>
  <option value="2015-00">2015</option>
  <option value="2015-02">February</option>
  <option value="2015-01">January</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step: Format your data into a single array/object that ng-options can work with. Multi-dimensonal data like you've got won't work.

Assuming this is your source data:

```
var data = {
    2015: {
        02: {monthname: 'February'},
        01: {monthname: 'January'}
    }
};
```

Format it into a flat object (key/value pairs):

```
var options = {};
for (var year in data) {
    if (!data.hasOwnProperty(year)) break;
    options[year+'-0'] = year;
    for (var month in data[year]) {
        if (!data[year].hasOwnProperty(month)) break;
        options[year+'-'+month] = data[year][month].monthname;
    }
}
```

That should result in `options` variable looking like this:

```
{
    '2015-0': 2015,
    '2015-2': 'February',
    '2015-1': 'January'
}
```

Put these options into $scope so you can use them:

```
$scope.options = options;
```

Then use ng-options as follows:

```
ng-options="key as value for (key,value) in options"
```

Detailed information about [ng-options formatting is available here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).

[Jsfiddle example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/10844/)